# Stringification of sequence members

Tags: indexeddb

According to the [IndexedDB spec](http://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#key-path-construct)

> A key path is a DOMString or sequence that defines how to
>   extract a key from a value. A valid key path is one of:
>
> - An empty DOMString.
> - An identifier, which is a DOMString matching the
>     IdentifierName production from the ECMAScript Language Specification
>     [ECMA-262].
> - A DOMString consisting of two or more identifiers
>     separated by periods (ASCII character code 46, U+002E FULL STOP).
> - A
>     non-empty sequence containing only strings conforming to
>     the above requirements.

Under the steps to ["evaluate a key path on a value"](http://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#evaluate-a-key-path-on-a-value),

> 1. If keyPath is a sequence, run these substeps:
>
>    1. Let result be a new Array ECMAScript object.
>    2. For each item in the keyPath sequence, run these substeps:
>
>       1. Let key be the result of recursively running the steps to extract a key from a value using a key path using item as keyPath and
>            value as value.
>       2. ReturnIfAbrupt(key)
>       3. If key is failure, abort the overall algorithm and return failure.
>       4. Append the result of the first sub-step to end of result.
>    3. Return result.
>
> This will only ever "recurse" one level since key path sequences can’t ever be nested.

According to the above (and the recursive [extract a key from a value using a key path](http://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#extract-a-key-from-a-value-using-a-key-path)), it would seem to me that a non-empty sequence containing non-strings (even with `toString()` methods) would not be permitted. Yet the [W3C tests](https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/blob/dccaa413ec1107e87b72245aa5ce837ee37ddff7/IndexedDB/keypath.htm#L110-L118) indicate at least stringifiable objects (not sure about boolean or number primitives) can be converted, and they [indeed pass](https://w3c-test.org/IndexedDB/keypath.htm).

Am I missing something in the spec which indicates that these should first be stringified before being validated/entered/utilized, and if so, under what conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens at the Web IDL layer that binds ECMAScript and the API. For example, with the `createObjectStore()` API, the input dictionary is defined as:

```
dictionary IDBObjectStoreParameters {
  (DOMString or sequence<DOMString>)? keyPath = null;
  boolean                             autoIncrement = false;
};
```

By the time the logic for [createObjectStore()](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbdatabase-createobjectstore) is executed, the IDL layer guarantees that the value for `keyPath` is either a DOMString, a sequence, or null, via the conversions defined in [WebIDL](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/). If something that can't be converted is passed, WebIDL defines that the method will throw before the API logic is reached.